# Dijkstra's algorithm when all edges have same weight

Tags: dijkstra

If all edges had the same weight in a given graph, will Dijkstra's algorithm still find the shortest path between 2 vertices?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes dijkstra algorithm can find the shortest path even when all edges have the same weight. dijkstra has time complexity O((V+E)logV).Instead you should choose BFS algorithm to do the same thing,because BFS has time complexity O(V+E),so BFS is asymptotically faster than dijkstra.

Comment: The time-complexity analysis in this answer is incorrect in. If you run dijkstra algorithm using a reasonable implementation, it will  run in O(V+E) time as well. In fact, both dijkstra and BFS can be run in O(E) time to find the shortest path between 2 given vertices.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would, But you might want to take a look at [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), wich solves the case you are refering to.
To find the path, you can make a recursive function that starts in the destiny node with flagged distance n, and moves to one of the neightbour nodes with flagged distance n-1